# Lost login password

Tags: boot, system-installation

Installed Ubuntu for first time and when I restarted I could not remember my password. How do I retrieve it or create new one?

Comment: Please search thoroughly before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy, just follow the below steps:-

> > 1. Restart into recovery.
> > 2. Drop to Root Shell Prompt.
> > 3. Type in `passwd username` and follow the instructions.

I'm marking this as the duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password).